# Coding 2^x with only +1 / -1 operations (unary append / remove a bit)

Tags: assembly

I have a class in assembly programming and we are at the start of the semester so I am really new at this. He gave us a made-up language in unary (ex: 3 = 111) to code `2^r1`. So let's say r1 = 111, then it should return 11111111 because 2^3 is 8.

We have 3 registers (r1, r2, r3) and these instructions:

- `push    r`         (adds 1 to the register r)
- `pop     r`         (removes 1 to the register r, does nothing if r is empty)
- `empty   r, lineX`  (goes the lineX if r is empty, if not, does nothing)
- `goto    lineX`     (goes to lineX)
- `concat  r, s`      (adds the number of 1 in register s into register r)
- `ret     r`         (returns the value of r and ends the program)

Suppose r2 and r3 are empty at the start. This is a bonus question where you can't use the concat function to make it harder. Can anyone help? I can do it with concat but not without.

Here is what I would do with concat:

```
  //Start:
     Push r1
     Push r3
  //L3: 
     Empty r1, end
  //L4:
     Empty r3, L8
     Push r2
     Pop r3
     Goto L4
  //L8:
     Concat r3, r2
     Pop r1
     Goto L3
  //End:
     Ret r2
```

My problem is that I can't mimic concat with another loop since my 2 other registers are needed for something else. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Since you don't have the option to treat those unary bit-patterns as base 2 or something (which interpret them as 2^x - 1), this is equivalent to implementing 2^x with numbers where you can only do +=1 and -=1 (with saturation to 0 on 0 - 1).  The fact that the numbers are represented as unary is basically irrelevant to the algorithm, given the limited operations.

Comment: Or since you say you can do it with concat, why not implement concat with a loop?

Comment: So your question would more accurately be "how do I implement concat using the other instructions?". That should be a fairly straightforward loop. Is there some specific part of that you are struggling with?

Comment: I added my solution with concat and the reason I can't implement it. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, maybe not as easy as I thought, since without concat you don't have a way to copy a register non-destructively.  And you're limited to only 3 registers, apparently; I missed that sentence that was originally buried at the end of a paragraph about something else.

Comment: Oh, you could empty out two other registers, and run a loop that pops one register while pushing *two* other registers, so when you're done you have two copies of the original (in the other two registers), and the original is zeroed.

Comment: I tried that... Let's say I want to have 2^3. I empty r1 and fill r2 and r3. r1=0,r2=3,r3=3. What then?

Answer (score 1):

The base solution is:

```
r2 = 1
r1 loop: double r2
```

(pseudocodish, imagine "rx loop" to mean the empty rx, loop body, pop rx, goto combination you already used in the example code)

You can double r2 using concat. I wonder if concat r2,r2 is allowed... :) Can we double r2 using the other operations and r3 instead?

like:

```
r3 = 0
r2 loop: {
   push r3
   push r3
}
```

and then copy it back into r2:

```
r3 loop: push r2
```

All enclosed in the r1 loop from the beginning of course. I'll leave translating the pseudocode into the real instructions to you.

Comment: I got it thanks to you! I feel dumb now that I see the solution and it is not that complicated ahah